# Smart word completion when in the middle of a word

Tags: autocompletion

Consider a file with the following two lines:

```
someLongFunction
someFunction
```

When I am in the insert mode in the middle of the second word

```
some|Function
```

and I press `Ctrl-n`, I get

```
someLongFunctionFunction
```

Is there a way of configuring Vim so that I get the following "smart" completion instead?

```
someLongFunction
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is only a quick mock-up answer (i.e. functional until it doesn't, or until it breaks something :) ), but it shows that "it is possible":

```
augroup completion
    autocmd!
    autocmd CompleteDone * call PostCompletion()
augroup END

function! PostCompletion()
    if !empty(v:completed_item)
        "check if text after current cursor position is part of the match
        let crt_word = expand('<cWORD>')
        let compl_word = v:completed_item['word']
        let lcw = len(compl_word)
        let leftover = strpart(crt_word, lcw)
        let lfl = len(leftover)
        if lfl > 0
            let endcompl = strpart(compl_word, lcw - lfl)
            if leftover ==# endcompl
                let cpos = getcurpos()
                normal dW
                call setpos('.', cpos)
            endif
        endif
    endif
endfunction
```

What the above code tries to do is: *after* completion, verifies if the WORD under cursor is longer than the completed word, and, if so, it further checks if its 'remainder' matches the last part of the completion (in your example, "Function"). If it does, the rest of the WORD is deleted (this assumes some things about cursor position).

(I'm pretty sure there are more clever ways to accomplish all this, and I'd like to see them!)